# Code Coverage subjects third party code to coverage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, pdb-files

In a project I'm working on there are two nuget packages which are included in code coverage if I don't specifically exclude these in the runsettings file, whereas other third party libraries aren't.

This seems to be because the packages in question generate a PDB file in the bin folder of the unit test project when building.

Why do some packages have a PDB file, whereas others don't? Is there a way to get a NuGet package without the PDB?

Is there a way to exclude third party libraries from code coverage?

Comment: Can't you just delete or rename those PDBs if you don't want coverage detection for those?

Comment: Nuget packages don't generate files, they contain them. If the developer decided to distribute PDB files in a given package that's what you get. As you say you can exclude them, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError absolutely, but when the test project is build (before a set of test runs), they are re-created...

Comment: @BenRobinson Within the project we measure code coverage (don't ask why), these mess up the statistics, so to speak. I do not want this to be an extra possible task for every nuget package add. It's good knowing they are included in the package, or not. Now I know the run settings file is probably the only way to achieve this.

Comment: PDB files carry useful information which can produce more detailed stacktraces - some developers package them in the nuget to help support any issues that people have when they use their library. Some coverage tools use these PDB files to help instrument the libraries sensibly - vstest is probably assuming that if you have the PDB you may have the source code and therefore instrument those libraries - just exclude them - or use a different tool that allows you more control over what is included/excluded when you run your tests with coverage.

Comment: You should seriously reconsider the title of your question here. Notice that what you end up asking at the end of your OP is not what the title suggests at all. You also seem to be asking two questions there, so I'd also consider splitting your question into two.

Comment: @julealgon Yes, you are correct. The title states my problem, whereas the questions address the (possible) cause of the problem. This is indeed not very clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found that you can use a `.runsettings` file to exclude libraries.

These can be used in TFS Build Definitions, or in Visual Studio by setting:

*Test > Test Settings > Select Test Settings File*

An example of a runsettings file where a library is excluded would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*Namespace.*.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*fluentassertions.*</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*htmlagilitypack.*</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
            <Attributes>
              <Exclude>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
              </Exclude>
            </Attributes>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```